# Create vector from loop in R

Tags: r

I'm basically trying to create a vector of NA's and numbers but in a very particular order.  Here's the code I have so far:

```
x<-rep(rep(2:1,c(2,3)),40)
dummy=1
for (i in 0:length(x))
{ ifelse(x[i+1]==2, print(NA), print(dummy))
 if(i %% 5 == 0) dummy=i+1
}
```

So my vector should look as follows (NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 6, 6, 6, etc).  However I cannot save this in this format so I can call it later in a matrix.  Any suggestions?  I have tried creating a vector of nothing and then filling it in the loop but that has worked with no avail either.

Liz
Statistics Student

Answer (score 3):

After alot of stubbornness on my part I have learned to vectorize these things completely, not sure if this helps in your particular situation but I would write:

```
x<-rep(rep(2:1,c(2,3)),40)
```

get the lead of your x with:

```
leadx=c(x[-1],NA)
```

write the numbers that you would get if there were no NAs

```
filler=rep(5*0:7+1,each=5)
```

get a vector with the right size filled in with NAs

```
y=rep(NA,length(x))
```

plug in the values of the filler into your NA vector

```
y[which(leadx!=2)]=filler[which(leadx!=2)]
```

check it out with:

```
head(y)

> [1] NA  1  1  1 NA NA  6  6  6 NA
```

Vectorized stuff tends to be faster than for loops and if statements. Good luck!

Edit: You can do it all in one line with:

```
y=ifelse(c(x[-1],NA)==2,NA,1)*rep(5*0:7+1,each=5)
```

Comment: Yes, I'm not familiar with the filler function but I see now how to use it to my advantage here.  This makes sense.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign your vector to something, rather than calling `print`, otherwise it will print to standard out.

```
out <- vector(length=length(x))

for (i in 0:length(x)) { 
  out[i] <- ifelse(x[i+1]==2, NA, dummy)
  if(i %% 5 == 0) dummy=i+1
}

> head(out, 10)
 [1] NA  1  1  1 NA NA  6  6  6 NA
>
```

Comment: Ah yes... I think my problem was specifying the length in the vector I tried to create and using print(NA).  Thanks for your help!